# Racket: How to write foldl using foldr

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm currently preparing for an exam and thought that writing foldl with foldr would be a nice question to get tested on.

Anyways, I know that (foldl f base lst) returns (f xn (f x(n-1) . . . (f x1 base)
with the lst being (x1 . . . xn)

So what I currently have is this:

```
(define (foldl/w/foldr f base lst)

(foldr (lambda (x y) (f y (f x base))) base lst)))
```

This doesn't quite work, and I am unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Haskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Haskell's [documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr) as a starting point (as mentioned by @soegaard in the comments), here's a working solution for this problem, using Racket syntax:

```
(define (foldl/w/foldr f base lst)
  ((foldr (λ (ele acc) (λ (x) (acc (f ele x))))
          identity
          lst)
   base))
```

For example:

```
(foldl/w/foldr cons '() '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
(foldl/w/foldr + 0 '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 15
```

The key to understand this is that we're accumulating *lambdas* with delayed computations, not values, and at the end we invoke all the chain of lambdas passing the base value to start the computation. Also notice that the `identity` procedure is used as the first accumulator, and we accumulate more lambdas on top of it. For instance, this call:

```
(foldl/w/foldr + 0 '(1 2))
```

Will be evaluated as follows:

```
((lambda (x)              ; this lambda is the value returned by foldr
   ((lambda (x)
      (identity (+ 1 x))) ; add first element in the list (this gets executed last)
    (+ 2 x)))             ; add second element in the list (this gets executed first)
 0) ; at the end, we invoke the chain of lambdas starting with the base value
=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Lisp programmer, so this maybe not syntactically perfect, but it will be something like

```
foldl f a l = (foldr (lambda (h p) (lambda (x) (p (f x h))) )
                     l
                     (lambda (x) (x))
                     a))
```

The trick is to accumulate function instead of result value. I am applying four arguments to foldr, because in this case regular foldr returns function, that will take "a" as an argument.